# $x^4+y^4+z^4=\frac{m}{n}$, find $m+n$.

Tags: systems-of-equations, resultant

$x^4+y^4+z^4$=$m\over n$

x, y, z are all real numbers,
satisfying $xy+yz+zx=1$ and $5\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)=12\left(y+\frac{1}{y}\right)=13\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)$

m, n are positive integers and their greatest common divisor is 1. Calculate m+n.

My thinkings so far are as follows:

- to operate such that we can arrange 5,12,13 into some kind of pythagorean triplets.
- to do whole square of x+1/x or x^2 + 1/x^2 such that
  the third term is a constant and can be moved to other side.

Comment: Hi, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write maths.

Comment: "5*(x+1/x)=12*(y+1/y)=13*(z+1/z)": What does this mean?  Does this mean that $$5 \times \frac{x+1}{x} = 12 \times \frac{y+1}{y} = 13 \times \frac{z+1}{z}~?$$  Alternatively, do you instead intend that $$5 \times \left[x + \frac{1}{x}\right] = 12 \times \left[y + \frac{1}{y}\right] = 13 \times \left[z + \frac{1}{z}\right] ~?$$

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for a MathJax tutorial.

Comment: @user2661923 Good question - I took the latter version. It has a nice solution.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I was wondering how you knew the OP's (i.e. original poster's) intent.  Did you by any chance place your fingertips on your monitor at the same time that the OP placed his fingertips on his monitor?  Are you from the planet Vulcan?

Comment: @user2661923 intended the second one. updated now. sorry for the trouble . Learning MathJax

Answer (score 4):

Taking [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of the polynomials given by
$$
f=5\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)-12\left(y+\frac{1}{y}\right),g=5\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)-13\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right), h=xy+yz+zx-1,
$$
set to zero, i.e., with
\begin{align*}
0 & = 5x^2y - 12xy^2 - 12x + 5y,\\
0 & = 5x^2z - 13xz^2 - 13x + 5z,\\
0 & = xy + xz + yz - 1
\end{align*}
we obtain the linear equation $13z=12y+25x$, and then by substituting $z$ and taking resultants again,
$$
(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{3},1\right),\; \left(-\frac{1}{5},-\frac{2}{3},-1\right).
$$
Hence we have
$$
x^4+y^4+z^4=\frac{60706}{50625}.
$$
So we have $(m,n)=(60706,50625)$, so that
$$
m+n=111331.
$$

Note: Over the complex numbers we obtain two additional solutions, namely
$$
(x,y,z)=(i,-i,i),(-i,i,-i).
$$
But then $x^4+y^4+z^4=3$, so that $m+n=4$.

Comment: Thanks  for the quick response, Can you  be bit more explicit. can't follow how you arrived at the first linear equation itself.

Comment: The first line is not clear. What are the resultants? The equation has no $x$ in it and too few $=$ signs. It is not clear how the  second line relates to the first.

Comment: @markvs Thank you, I have edited.

Comment: $f,g$ are not polynomials. The equation $13z=...$ still does not contain $x$.

Comment: The equation 13z=... still does not contain $x$ and too few $=$.

Comment: Yes, now it has $x$. But why "then" in "and then"?

Answer (score 1):

Notice if $(x,y,z)$ satisfies the two conditions, so does $(-x,-y,-z)$. Furthermore, it is clear $x,y,z$ have the same sign. Since $(x,y,z)$ and $(-x,-y,-z)$ gives the same $\frac{m}{n}$, we only need to consider the case $x,y,z > 0$.

Take three numbers $\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ such that
$$x = \tan\alpha, y = \tan\beta, z = \tan\gamma$$

Recall the three angle summation formula for tangent, we have
$$\begin{align}\tan(\alpha+\beta+\gamma) 
&= \frac{\tan\alpha + \tan\beta + \tan\gamma - \tan\alpha\tan\beta\tan\gamma}{1 - \tan\alpha\tan\beta - \tan\beta\tan\gamma - \tan\gamma\tan\alpha}\\
&= \frac{x+y+z - xyz}{1 -xy - yz -zx}\\&= \infty\end{align}$$
This implies $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = (N + \frac12)\pi$ for some integer $N$.

Since $\alpha + \beta + \gamma \in (0,\frac32\pi)$, this forces $N = 0$ and
hence $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Notice
$$\frac{2}{x+\frac1x} = \sin(2\alpha),\quad
\frac{2}{y+\frac1y} = \sin(2\beta)\quad\text{ and }\quad
\frac{2}{z+\frac1z} = \sin(2\gamma)$$
the condition
$$5\left(x+\frac1x\right) = 12\left(y  + \frac1y\right) = 13\left(z + \frac1z\right)$$
is equivalent to

$$\sin(2\alpha) : \sin(2\beta) : \sin(2\gamma) = 5 : 12 : 13 \tag{*1}$$

Since $5^2 + 12^2 = 13^2$, we find

$$\sin^2(2\alpha) + \sin^2(2\beta) = \sin^2(2\gamma)\tag{*2}$$
With a little bit of algebra, one can verify when $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \frac{\pi}{2}$, one has the "cosine rule":

$$\cos(2\gamma) = \frac{\sin^2(2\alpha) + \sin^2(2\beta) - \sin^2(2\gamma)}{2\sin(2\alpha)\sin(2\beta)}$$

$(*2)$ tell us  $\cos(2\gamma) = 0 \implies \gamma = \frac{\pi}{4} \implies z = \tan\gamma = 1$. Plug this into $(*1)$, we get

$$
\begin{cases}
\sin(2\alpha) = \frac{5}{13}\\
\sin(2\beta)  = \frac{12}{13}
\end{cases}
\quad\implies\quad
\begin{cases}
\cos(2\alpha) = \frac{12}{13}\\
\cos(2\beta)  = \frac{5}{13}
\end{cases}
$$
This leads to
$$\begin{align}
x &= \tan \alpha = \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(2\alpha)}{1 + \cos(2\alpha)}}
= \sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{12}{13}}{1+\frac{12}{13}}} = \frac15\\
y &= \tan \beta = \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(2\beta)}{1 + \cos(2\beta)}}
= \sqrt{\frac{1-\frac{5}{13}}{1+\frac{5}{13}}} = \frac23\\
\end{align}
$$
As a result
$$\frac{m}{n} = x^4 + y^4 + z^4 = \frac1{5^4} + \frac{2^4}{3^4} + 1^4 = \frac{60706}{50625}$$
This leads to $m + n = 60706 + 50625 = 111331$.